# DataView Update itself to the new rowfilter

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0, datatable, dataview

I am trying to retain some rows in dataview for some operations to perform after I get the filtered rows, but the issue is , every time the code runs, the dataview is updated to the filter last applied. Here is the code snippest.

```
If dsEmp.Tables.Count > 0 Then
    dvEmp = dsEmp.Tables(0).DefaultView
    dvEmp.RowFilter = "IDENTIFICATION_CODE = '" & IDENTIFICATION_CODE & "' and EMPLOYEE_DESC =  'Employment1'"
    Dim dv1 As DataView = dvEmp
    dvEmp.RowFilter = ""
    If dsEmp.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 1 Then
        dvEmp2 = New DataView
        dvEmp2 = dsEmp.Tables(0).DefaultView
        dvEmp2.RowFilter = "IDENTIFICATION_CODE = '" & IDENTIFICATION_CODE & "' and EMPLOYEE_DESC =  'Employment2'"
        Dim dv2 As DataView = dvEmp2
        dvEmp2.RowFilter = ""
    End If
    If dsEmp.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 2 Then
        dvEmpPrevious = New DataView
        dvEmpPrevious = dsEmp.Tables(0).DefaultView
        dvEmpPrevious.RowFilter = "IDENTIFICATION_CODE = '" & IDENTIFICATION_CODE & "' and EMPLOYEE_DESC =  'Employment3'"
        Dim dv3 As DataView = dvEmpPrevious
        dvEmpPrevious.RowFilter = ""
    End If
End If
```

but when I check the value of dv1, after second filter, it has the different values in it.

Could any one give some solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just changing the name of the variables but every DataView above is still referencing the same DataView (the DefaultView of the table). So when you reset the RowFilter you apply this change to the DefaultView as well.

If you want to have different views with different filters then you need to create a DataView passing the source DataTable

```
dvEmp = new DataView(dsEmp.Tables(0))
dvEmp.RowFilter = "IDENTIFICATION_CODE = '" & IDENTIFICATION_CODE & "' and EMPLOYEE_DESC =  'Employment1'"
```

Now the dvEmp is no more referencing the DefaultView of the DataTable and it should maintain the correct RowFilter applied

Of course, you should use the filtered DataView to test the number of records present in the DataView after the filter not the DataTable.
The DataTable will contain always the same number of records

```
If dvEmp.Count > 1 Then
   .....
```

Comment: Thanks Steve for the reply and edit :)... However I just got the solution  and that was to save each row I filter into a data table and use that data table instead of that datarow. I know its not optimized but its working ;)